# String with functions to JSON

Tags: json, string, function, extjs

I need to turn this string:

```
"{
   click : myClickFunction,
   render : myRenderFunction
}"
```

or some variation of it,

into :

```
{
   click : myClickFunction,
   render : myRenderFunction
}
```

where `myClickFunction` and `myRenderFunction` are functions defined else where and are not strings

Comment: You would be better off using the new MVC functionality in Ext5 to resolve the string names to controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function myClickFunction (test) {
   return "Foo";
}

function myRenderFunction (test) {
    return "Bar";
}
var mystring = "{click : myClickFunction,render : myRenderFunction}";

var obj=eval("("+mystring+")");
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.click());
console.log(obj.render());
```